# Node .replace() only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, postgresql, replace

When I try to remove line endings, it only works about 75% of the time and not other times. I've tried multiple permutations of `.replace()` to the same effect; that is, sometimes, it will still contain `\n`. Why is this happening, and what can I do to make this work all the time rather than just occasionally?

```js
const transformStream = new stream.Transform({
  transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    const data = chunk.toString()
      // remove line endings from stream, making one long line
      .replace(/(\n)|(\r)|(\\")|(\\\\)|(\\n)|(\\r)/gm, "");
    callback(null, data);
  }
});
```

I have tried the following:

- `.replace(/[\n\r]/g)`
- `.replace(/[\n\r]|(\n)|(\r)|(\\n)|(\\r)/g)`

And other similar variations, but nothing has achieved the desired results so far.

**EDIT:**

Here is the piece of data that Postgres complains about (we are streaming the data to Postgres). The actual file is 101MB and I cannot upload it for reasons of privacy.

```
{
  result: 'There was a problem with the JSON content.',
  message: 'invalid input syntax for type json',
  detail: 'Character with value 0x0a must be escaped.',
  where: 'JSON data, line 1: ...rice_level"}},"barcodes":[],"id":"i0","name":"Rum\n'
}
```

What am I missing here? We're using `replace()` to replace `\n` and `\\n`.
And again, if I run it a second time, it will usually go through without any issue. If not, I just keep running it and eventually it will go through.

Comment: Show input that it doesn't work with

Comment: did you tried to split your `replaces` to `replace(/\r\n/g, "\n")` (windows) and `replace(/\r/g, '')` (empty strings) and also `replace(/\\n/g, '\n').replace(/\\r/g, '')` (newline and carriage return) and so on... so that you will have: `const data = chunk.toString().replace(..).replace(..).replace(..)`

Comment: Because if it happens sometimes, so I am sure that it might be due to variations in line ending characters or unexpected characters in the data.

Comment: Stream chunks are under no obligation not to be split right in the middle of the contiguous multi-character sequence you're looking for. e.g. if you're hoping to find `ab`  the first chunk might end with `a` and the next chunk might begin with `b` meaning you failed to find `ab` in either chunk, yet the concatenated sequence of chunks contained `ab`.  This will impair your ability to reliably locate two-character sequences.

Comment: It also looks like you're trying to directly transform JSON text (which is structured data encoded in JSON format), which is fundamentally different from trying to transform the structured data that was encoded.  You're better off decoding the JSON, then transforming any string data you want to transform, then re-encoding back to JSON.  That way you don't corrupt any escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks @Wyck. I think that's why we keep getting different failed strings but for the same reason. I'll look into a pre-parser to strip these newlines.